# Phase detection with non-ideal PFD

Tags: frequency, high-frequency, pll, phase

I'm trying to simulate for Phase Frequency Detector with the following implementation: 
[image]

and inside NAND_PFD:
[image]

NOTE: the triangles on the right are inverters and not amplifiers.

I'm currently getting a \$Clk_{ref}\rightarrow{Up}\$ delays which are represented in this sumulation:
[image]

same for \$Clk_{Vco}\rightarrow{Down}\$.

\$Clk_{Vco}\$ is the voltage that should come out of the VCO in a general PLL. here I picked a frequency just for simulation.

looking at the sate machine:

[image]

when \$ Up = Down = 0 \$ and \$ Clk_{Vco} \$ goes up, \$ Down \$ should go up. 
in most articles that I've read, this change appears exactly in the area of phase difference, which appears that the change is immediate and without delay.like in this image: 
[image]

how can we interpret this delay in terms of phase detection? 
should the phase detection appear exactly at the same time \$ Up/Down \$ change? or we just need the information of the widths of change and deliver that to the PLL to do it's job and it doesn't matter when we detected the change?

here is a longer simulation of which I'm trying to verify that the pattern of phase detecting right:
[image]

the transistors sizing was done as the following:

[image]

by using ESDnfet, and ESDpfet transistors in 28n technology, with a library called cmos32lp. (in virtuoso).

Note: I still don't know what ESDnfet and ESDpfet mean, and I randomly picked them and I would be glad if someone knows this library can tell me if picking other kind of transistors would make a difference.

\$ Clk_{Vco} \$ and \$ Clk_{ref} \$ were defined as the following:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qME4e.png)

[image]

[image]

Comment: 1) explain why you think that there should not be any delay between the signals 2a) Cref and Cout aren't capacitors, they're voltages. Call then Vref and Vout instead. 2b) What if a NAND gate had a delay of 1 second, would that affect the maximum frequency at which the circuit can operate at? +1 for providing all needed details in your question.

Comment: How's a delay of **less than one nanosecond** "huge"? These are pretty fast gates you are simulating there. The real thing with 74HC gates would be about 10 times slower.

Comment: @Janka, it seems logical what you're trying to say, but in all the articles i read, i've noticed that the change in Up/Down appears exactly after the change in the Clk,ref/Clk Cout. the change doesn't really appear vertically on the same scale? does that affect the idea of phase detecting? shouldn't the indication be right under the area were the clocks are out of phase?

Comment: The shortest signal path from input to output is trough three NANDs plus an inverter. With 74HC gates, this means a delay of about 28ns before any change at an input can do anything to the output. Within an ASIC, you may get down to a few ns, but certainly not down to less than one nanosecond. That's unrealistic.

Comment: As long as signals are propagating through real logic gates there will be some delay from the input events to the change in an output. Timing diagrams like the one you added are generally assumed to be **ideal** and do not reflect actual delays.

Comment: @ElliotAlderson  alright, in the ideal case I was able to check if the phase detector works fine by estimating the width of the Up and Down pulses compared to the Phase difference like it appears in the ideal photo that I attached, now I'm supposed to eye-track this change as a function of time more carefully because they're not vertically aligned?

Comment: For minimal delays , use Current Mode Logic (CML)

Comment: @SunnyskyguyEE75 the gates were built from zero by using ESDnfet, and ESDpfet transistors. (28n technology)
do you suggest us to use ideal gates? but that's the point, we wanted simulate for non-ideal case.
by the way, do you know what ESDnfet and ESDpfet mean? they were randomly picked.

Comment: No I don't know but this may be of interest http://tera.yonsei.ac.kr/publication/pdf/Jour_2015_KDH_TCAS1.pdf

Comment: *using ESDnfet, and ESDpfet transistors* Sounds like these are transistors which have some form of ESD protection and/or are used as ESD protection. **You should not use these in a typical design**. Randomly picking a component isn't how a good designer works, so **read the manual** and pick the right components. Use "nfet" and "pfet" instead. Read about ESD here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electrostatic_discharge

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not going to work through the details of your specific schematic. I just want to make a few general statements:

- As long as the transfer function of your detector is monotonic, it can be used to drive the frequency error of your PLL to zero. The input-to-output delay of the detector doesn't affect this.
- As long as the delays from the two inputs to the output are *matched*, you can also drive the phase error to zero. If not, you're left with a small residual constant phase error, which can usually be compensated for by other means.

Comment: first of all thanks for the reply!
I attached a new simulation that shows a monotonic increase in the width of the UP signal.
I need to think about this result and the delay matching that you talked about.
 I still can't explain why Up starts with 1.9 v.
by the way, if we're already talking about this, in this case, I should always expect a periodic behavior of up signal over time, which means, I'm not expecting that Down starts have increasing widths all of a sudden (except in case the input frequencies themselves change over time, for example, Vco signal which is affected by temperature)

Answer (score 0):

Lets experiment.

To better understand the behavior, set your Fref input to 300MHz at 50% duty-cycle with 0.3nanosecond Trise/Tfall; set your Fvar input to 310MHz input at 45% duty-cycle with 0.4 nanosecond Trise/Tfall.

Notice these are not the same frequency, so your output waveform (the UP and the DOWN pulses) will display a **beatnote** at 10MHz or 100 nanosecond. **At various time-alignments, your output pulses will become trash.** For a tight phaselock, you want the region of **TRASH** to be as narrow as possible, which requires the crucial gates be as fast as possible. Not all gates are crucial.

Out of 100nanosecond (1/10Mhz) observation window, you will have 30+ testing events. You can probably raise the testing frequency to 600 and 610MHz, or even to 1,000 and 1,010 MHz. Experiment with duty cycle and rise/fall times.

Now you need to understand what best drives your ChargePump, for best rectangular current switching.

And you should ask your system-people what residual phasenoise floor is needed, and then collaborate with them on how a time-edge-wander of 100 picosecond random RMS will degrade your phasenoise floor.

Lets predict the phase noise. I see 3 gates delay, plus the output buffer, for the leading edge. Assume gate bandwidth is 40GigaHertz. Assume the equivalent  Rnoise in each gate&buffer is 10,000 ohms (could be lower).
What is the total integrated Vnoise voltage in each gate?

Vnoise = sqrt(40,000,000,000) * 12 nanoVolts/rtHz at 10Kohms

Vnoise = 2e+5 * 12e-9 = 24e(+5-9) = 24e-4 = 2.4e-3 = 2.4 milliVolts.

The Time Jitter per gate is Vnoise/Slewrate.

Assume SlewRate is 2 volts in 20 picoSeconds, or 100Billion volts per second or 1e+11 volts/second.

TimeJitter Tj is Vnoise/Slewrate = 2.4e-3/1e+11 = 2.4e-14 = 24 femtoSeconds

per gate/buffer.

With Four gates/buffers in the path to create the initial edge of output pulses, your variance increases by 4, and your RMS ( the standard deviation) increases by sqrt(4) or factor of 2.

Thus TimeJitter is sqrt(4) * 24 femtoSeconds, = 50 femtoSeconds RMS.

Comment: here is what I got:
https://imgur.com/KiL4wPc 
can you explain further what is beatnote?

Comment: The middle waveform seems to start repeating, at 87 nanoseconds. Is this a transistor-level simulation? or a gate-level? of course with 100Billion volt/second edges, most any simulation will seem like gate-level. If transistor-level sim, then increase to 1,000MHz and 1,005MHz and run the simulation for 200 nanoSeconds; we want to observe failure of the logic, when output pulses FAIL to reach full height; we want to break the logic behavior and start to see the transistor behavior.

Comment: this is transistor level. here is the new simulation with 1000Mhz and 1005Mhz: https://imgur.com/ZQ4Wqh5, I think what we're trying to observe is the width of the pulse, that will determine and affect the charge pump functioning. are you trying to observe the deadzone range?

Comment: yes --- trying to find incomplete-swing less-than-full-height pulses. I see none. Of course the Charge Pump may not respond to 50 picoSecond pulses.